# Phaser.io atlas animation

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, phaser-framework, pixi.js

- I created a car animation in blender from top view. And rendered the animation as a picture sequence.
- Then created the atlas using shoebox, with trim alpha option set to True, in order to reduce the size (cars.png, cars.js)
- Now that I play the animation in Phaser, the car gets anchored in one position and does not go from one end to the other.
- How do I get the animation to play so that Phaser reads the sourcesize when playing the animation. 
  The picture render from blender is the same as the phaser canvas window. But as I trim it in Shoebox to remove the alpha, I am unable to anchor the car properly.
- Could anyone point out what I may be missing.

[image]

```
preload: function () {

this.load.atlas('carImg', 'images/cars.png', 'images/cars.js', Phaser.Loader.TEXTURE_ATLAS_JSON_HASH);

}

create: function () {

this.carSprite = this.add.sprite(300, 300, 'carImg');
this.carSprite.animations.add('car',Phaser.Animation.generateFrameNames('Car', 0, 200, '.png', 4), 18, true);
this.carSprite.animations.play('car',18,true);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phaser will respect and use the trim / sourceSize values in an atlas, so long as it has been loaded correctly. You should usually use the extension 'json' for the data file, not 'js'. Also, are you sure it is definitely in a HASH format? If you remove that argument Phaser will figure it out for you automatically from the source file when it inspects it.

Also, in your code you create an animation called 'car', but are playing an animation called 'bus'. Not sure if you just selectively copy pasted that code, but the animation keys need to match.

Comment: Thanks a ton for pointing that mistake for car/bus, I had copied the wrong line in stack overflow.  And regarding js and json, shoe box by default exported .js and I didn't bother modifying it. But if you say that is necessary then will rectify that. Hash: yes it is as the body starts with { frames:{ , and not { frames: [. But @ photonstorm, then how do I go about animating the car from one direction to the other without path animation as my next scene is a isometric scene and I need to show the car turning. Please do suggest. Thanks

Comment: I need to play the rendered picture sequence as atlas animation, so do I put trim alpha as false from shoebox??  The loading time will increase

Comment: Thanks, the missing part of the json was trimmed:'true', apparently that was not explicitly put by shoebox. Now it's working perfectly